# How to call callback provided by render prop from its parent component using hooks between renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to close a popover that can only be closed via a close callback in its render props. I was wondering how I can use hooks or some other strategy to save this callback function between renders to call it in a useEffect.  I tried using useContext to no avail: https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-close-from-content-y637f

Comment: I was advised the following elsewhere: https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-close-from-content-bss42 `but the real correct solution is to not have this StatefulPopover be stateful if you need to control it from outside. you should be telling it if it's open or not with a prop`. I also asked: `I was planning on building a menu bar with dropdown menus made up of these popovers and was wondering how many of these fileMenuIsOpen, etc would be too much` to which I got: `you can also do things like having an identifier for the currently open popup as the state, so e.g. null or 'FIRST' or 'SECOND'

Comment: `...you probably don't need multiple open at once, so reducing the state to a single value might be desirable. you could try to abstract out a component that manages the popup state, and gives the child a function like onAction(promise). and the reusable popup component can manage if it's open, and set itself to closed when the promise resolves, so you don't need to repeat that logic everywhere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ref to save the close function for use in useEffect. Here is a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-close-from-content-sgmgs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Block } from "baseui/block";
import { Button } from "baseui/button";
import { StatefulPopover } from "baseui/popover";

export default () => {
  const closeRef = useRef();
  const [state, setState] = useState({ isSaving: false });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.isSaving) {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("closing", closeRef.current);
        // close popover from here
        closeRef.current && closeRef.current();
        setState({ isSaving: false });
      }, 5000);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      };
    }
  }, [state.isSaving]);
  const onSave = () => {
    console.log("save btn clicked");
    setState({ isSaving: true });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <StatefulPopover
        content={(
          { close } // I need to call close per this library's API to close
        ) => {
          closeRef.current = close;
          return (
            <Block padding="scale500" maxWidth="300px">
              <Block paddingBottom="scale400">
                content render prop is passed a <code>close()</code> callback so
                it you can manually trigger popover close from within
              </Block>
              <Button isLoading={state.isSaving} onClick={onSave}>
                Save
              </Button>
            </Block>
          );
        }}
      >
        <Button>Click Me</Button>
      </StatefulPopover>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Context isn't working as you expect because you are attempting to access the context using `useContext` outside of the Provider. In order to access the value from the Provider, the `useContext` hooks must be utilized inside of a child component of the context Provider. Otherwise, the `useContext` will just get the default value passed into `createContext`.